nextjs with mui emotion cache append all styles on every hot update
When I save some changes in component and hot update hits, on the same update, number of styles in head element generated by MUI almost double and same with another hot update.
After couple of changes in component browser freeze and it has over 5000 <style /> tags in <head /> tag, some with 4 identical styles
firefox dev tools <style />
firefox freeze
When I remove EmotionCacheProvider it works, but MUI styles are generated last witch breakes some styles.
I updated modules to latest, deleted .next folder... but problem still occures
